# Payable constructor gives revert message

Tags: solidity, remix, constructor, revert-opcode

I am trying to execute the following contract on remixe IDE:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.4;
contract GuessTheNumberChallenge {
    constructor() public payable {
        require(msg.value == 1 ether);
    }

}
```

I am getting the following message and I am showing the Debug message also:

> VM error: revert. revert  The transaction has been reverted to the
>   initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send
>   value and the value you send should be less than your current
>   balance.  Debug the transaction to get more information. creation of
>   GuessTheNumberChallenge pending...
>   [vm]from:0xca3...a733cto:GuessTheNumberChallenge.(constructor)value:0
>   weidata:0x608...00032logs:0hash:0x3c2...162d0  status     0x0 Transaction
>   mined but execution failed  transaction hash
>     0x3c204d4cdd45c410f8ab98cf5db12ea1b31fbde7c35296f6820e2554b4f162d0 
>   contract address  0x08970fed061e7747cd9a38d680a601510cb659fb  from
>     0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c  to
>     GuessTheNumberChallenge.(constructor) (Contract Creation - Step 0) 
>   gas   3000000 gas   transaction cost  59197 gas   execution cost  45
>   gas   hash
>     0x3c204d4cdd45c410f8ab98cf5db12ea1b31fbde7c35296f6820e2554b4f162d0 
>   input     0x608...00032  decoded input    {}  decoded output   -   logs   []
>   value     0 wei

Somebody please guide me.

I am adding the image for execution:
[image: Adding 10 Ether in value]

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top right.

You will have to send 1 ether when you deploy the contract because the contract requires it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am already adding 10 in the value text box, I have even tried to select 'Ether' from the drop down list. I have attached the image. But I am still getting the revert message. Note that the deploy button is red. Somebody please guide me.

Comment: You sent 10 Wei which is nowhere near 10 Eth. Common mistake. Change the unit to Eth. Thanks for accepting my answer. ;-)

Comment: Excuse me , sir I tried with 10 Ether also but I am still getting revert message. Can i get your email address.

Comment: Thanks it worked, I have to give just 1 ether.

Comment: I'm on LinkedIn.